# Can Spark Dataframe's where clause take a variable as an argument?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running where clause from Spark Dataframe. When I put String variable as argument, it throws me an error message. If I copy that string and put that one in the query, it works.

```
val a = """col("foo")==="bar" || col("abc")==="def""""
val df = df_.where(a)
```

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:

== SQL ==
col("foo")==="bar" || col("abc")==="def"
---------------^^^
```

If I try without using variable, it works.

```
val df = df_.where(col("foo")==="bar" || col("abc")==="def")
```

Answer (score 3):

If expression is a string it should be a syntactically valid SQL, i.e.

```
"""foo = 'bar' AND abc = 'def'"""
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as a `String`, but you can save the `where` condition as a `Column`-type value, as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val df = Seq(
  ("bar", "x"), ("zz", "y"), ("mm", "def")
).toDF("foo", "abc")

val cond: Column = col("foo") === "bar" || col("abc") === "def"

df.where(cond).show
// +---+---+
// |foo|abc|
// +---+---+
// |bar|  x|
// | mm|def|
// +---+---+
```